# O que é necessário para OCR Android

Tags: android, ocr

Ja vi vários artigos e perguntas em fóruns e muitos outros sites na internet, sei o que é necessário para um ocr básico, ja consegui fazer um e tals mas o que vou perguntar aqui é mais especifico com relação ao assunto.
Para um OCR android é necessário.
- Camera
- API OCR (Tesseract por exemplo)

Mas eu gostaria de saber o seguinte.
1 - Quando estiver apontando para o texto quando a camera consiga foco capture a imagem e analise com a API OCR para localizar o texto daquele momento sem ter que tirar uma foto, salvar e analisar o JPEG.

2 - Como poderia buscar na imagem captura palavras especificas.

3 - Colocar alguma arte na tela como uns pontos em volta das letras como ja vi em alguns outros apps OCR.

Sei que pode ser complicado, bem, para mim é bastante, mas se tiver algum que possa dar algum luz, alguma direção, não precisa obviamente uma solução pronta mas quais classes do android eu talvez usaria para isso ai eu estudo elas.

Comment: Você pode fornecer mais detalhes do seu uso intencionado? Eu pergunto isso porque se você precisa fazer um sistema que **de fato** reconheça o texto (isto é, extraia da imagem a string para alguma outra manipulação posterior), seu único caminho é mesmo OCR. Mas, se você apenas intenciona reconhecer um elemento visual (pra marcá-lo na imagem, colocar arte ao redor, etc, etc), você não necessariamente precisa de OCR. Uma alternativa nesse sentido é usar um detector de Cascata. (continua...)

Comment: O [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html), por exemplo, tem porte para Android e já conta com [uma ótima implementação desse detector](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html). Você pode aprender com esse tutorial a treiná-lo para detectar qualquer coisa: http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

Answer (score 5):

Você vai ficar completamente engessado se utilizar API's de OCR prontas, não vai ter como grifar muito menos colocar pontos ao redor de uma palavra específica,  nada neste sentido será possível, um OCR tem apenas a função de tentar extrair as letras de uma imagem e retornar em modo texto.

Como comentado pelo @LuizVieira o [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) vai ser o teu braço direito para este tipo de projeto, você realmente pode treinar cada letra e número do alfabeto para fazer comparações em real-time, este treino tem que possuir escala invariante ou seja não importa o tamanho da fonte, não importa a escala, mesmo assim ele terá que saber de qual letra se trata.

Eu posso te dar os passos básicos de como isso pode ser feito utilizando o `OpenCV` para extrair os pixels e sem usar o `OpenCV` para treinar

- Crie vetores com os padrões de todas as letras e números, você vai
  precisar recortar cada letra e número, extraia os pixels de cada um,
  use o `OpenCV` ele tem funções prontas para extração de pixels, armazene da maneira que achar conveniente.
- Agora você tem a base para comparação, você vai querer comparar cada
  letra capturada em tempo real com os padrões extraídos, use o
  `OpenCV` para recortar cada letra de seus textos em tempo real, como
  saber onde cada letra começa e termina enquanto você aponta a câmera
  do seu celular ? Este algorítimo pode ser feito comparando
  horizontalmente cada pixel até encontrar o inicio e fim de cada
  letra, estamos falando de algo básico aqui, 99% dos textos estão em
  preto com fundo branco (é super importante definir qual é a cor
  predominante do fundo do texto, você pode conseguir isso escrevendo
  um histograma RGB), ou simplesmente forçar tudo a ficar em preto e branco o que é realmente uma ótima ideia, vamos focar no fundo branco pra caráter de
  exemplo, caminhe até o pixel branco acabar marque a posição, neste
  ponto vai começar o novo pixel (preto neste caso), caminhe até o
  pixel preto acabar marque a posição, isso vai te falar onde recortar
  cada letra ou número (inicio e fim), você acabou de
  segmentar(separar) letras em tempo real.
- Perfeito recortou a letra do texto, agora extraia os pixels dela,
  assim como no primeiro passo feito para construir seu banco.
- Agora compare o que foi extraído do texto com o seu banco de dados,
  em álgebra linear tem um conceito chamado [espaço linear](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%A7o_vetorial), neste caso
  teremos quais pixels aparecem com mais frequência, é uma maneira
  simples que pode ser usada para mensural qual é a letra mais
  parecida.
- Monte cada palavra baseado neste rank (quanto maior o cosseno
  retornado pelo espaço linear melhor) e surpresa se essa palavra for uma `específica` você terá a posição dela inteira (inicio, fim) e poderá utilizar o `OpenCV` novamente para inserir alguma arte desejada já que agora você sabe a posição exata dela dentro do texto.

Eu acabei de descrever uma maneira simples de criar um `OCR`, sem utilizar `escala invariante`, ao invés de usar `espaço linear` você pode treinar cada letra e número usando o `OpenCV`, Existe a função [SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html) no `OpenCV`que aplica escala invariante e é mais rápido que o seu antecessor [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform), o básico o grosso de como tudo funciona é isso ai.

Comment: Ederwander, você poderia me mandar seu email para conversarmos?